# Dialog to pick number and String

Tags: android, dialog, numbers, picker

i need a dialog thats allows me to pick a number and one String out of three.
User should pick a String (Year,Month,Weeks) and then pick the number of y,m or w.

Any one knows out to get that to look like something like this

[image]

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: Search for `DatePickerDialog`

Comment: I know about that one, and i have used in my app, but now i need one like the one i asked.. Is not like a date but more like a Age picker

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624283/android-numberpicker-with-strings see this

Comment: you can check out functionality url :http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/07/material-design-datetime-picker-for.html

Comment: @Arjunsaini thats just what i want, i will try to make a custom numberpicker too. Thank you

Comment: Welcome.... @DiogoRosa.....

Comment: https://github.com/KasualBusiness/MaterialNumberPicker see this example more help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yes i just used this code here and changed a few things that i needed, this does the trick

```
public void AgeDialog(){

    final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setCancelable(false);

    LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    final NumberPicker number =new NumberPicker((this));
    number.setMaxValue(12);
    number.setMinValue(1);
    number.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    number.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    final NumberPicker ageUnitss = new NumberPicker(this);
    final String arrays[] = new String[3];
    arrays[0]="Years";
    arrays[1]="Months";
    arrays[2]="Days";

    ageUnitss.setMaxValue(2);
    ageUnitss.setMinValue(0);
    ageUnitss.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    ageUnitss.setDisplayedValues(arrays);
    ageUnitss.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);


    l1.addView(number);
    l1.addView(ageUnitss);

    l1.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    alert.setView(l1);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            ageUnits = arrays[(ageUnitss.getValue())];
            age = number.getValue();
            fragment1.setAgeText(age +" "+ageUnits);
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });

    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these libraries:[NumberPicker](https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker),[VNTNumberPickerPreference](https://github.com/vanniktech/VNTNumberPickerPreference)