# how do i show the array adapter data to number picker

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to create a number picker with string and want to add the string from web service, json parsing was successful now i want to show it in picker. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: use spinner and set your data in spinner adapter

Comment: add the data collected from parsed json and simply put it in an arraylist or something and yes, put it on a spinner.

Comment: thanku sir for ur response, but i want picker rather than spinner. is it possible?

Comment: @ninu chck this ans it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624283/android-numberpicker-with-strings